# textfield and textview for sprite

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, uitextview, sprite

I need to use `uitextfield` and `uitextview` as sprites in my xcode app. How can I define them?

A label can be defined like

```
CCLabelBMFont *StatusLabel;
```

How can I use textfield and textview?

Comment: is there any idea to add some contents into cocos2d page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer the link below
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/embedded/cocos2d-x/d6/d5c/class_c_c_text_field_t_t_f.html